# How can i populate 3 columns with a single array of strings (Javascript, HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

If I have an array with 15 strings stored in, and I want to populate 3 columns (ideally 3 bootstrap columns made with divs, but can be any as long as they're responsive) with equally 5 strings each column starting from the first, what is an easy method to do so in javascript/jQuery?

Right now I'm thinking of doing **three** separate **for loops**, checking `array[n]` to append `<li>` 5 times to three different `<ul>` to which I assign an ID, but all sounds like there may be an easier way to achieve it.

Maybe a css trick to divide the 15 strings into three columns?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `splice` to extract the first 5 elements from your array into a new array, then use `join()` to join the elements. Based on your description this code should work:

**Updated**

```js
let arr = [0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
let columns = [".col1", ".col2", ".col3"]
for(let i = 0; i<3; i++)
  document.querySelector(columns[i]).innerHTML = `<li>${arr.splice(0, 5).join("</li><li>")}</li>`;
```

```css
body{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<ul class="col1"></ul>
<ul class="col2"></ul>
<ul class="col3"></ul>
```

Notice that I have used numbers instead of strings inside the array because I was too lazy to think about cool strings :)

**Attention**: after this operation, your `arr` will be empty.

Comment: This seems pretty solid, i'd set the var "arr" value from the db array on page load so it being emptied shouldn't be an issue i guess

Comment: This doesn't put em vertically each in a <li> thought, i'm trying to figure out the right way to do so, but from what i see it changes everything